# Any way to cast a table with one value as a scalar type? (Integer, String, etc.)

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

Here is what I would like to do:

```
declare maxNum integer;    
maxNum = select MAX(rn) from :ColumnList;
```

The sql statement returns a table with one row/col (one value).

Is there an easy way to assign this value to a scalar variable?

Answer (score 3):

The variable will be stored as an integer with this syntax.

```
declare maxNum integer;    
select MAX(rn) into maxNum from :ColumnList;
```

Edit: Thanks to Lars Br. for the explanation why this works.

Comment: The `SELECT INTO` form is plain SQL standard. nothing weird there. The idea is that a `SELECT` generates another table-like thing (another relation in relational algebra) and not just a line with somehow connected scalar values. In order to "extract" individual values out of a single row the `SELECT INTO` syntax exists.